# Copying tab delimited values to datagridview from Clipboard

Tags: c#

The original data in the clipboard looks like this when I copy it from the application

```
Trade Info

NE62 -- NE62

Symbol      Side        Quantity        Avg Price       ClientAcct      

ESU8        BUY     100     2809.2500       35199008        
FLT.V       SELL        15,000      1.7040      tB324aV     
TRST.TO     SELL        4,850       7.1500      tB324aVV        
YGR.TO      SELL        5,200       5.3806      tB324aV
```

---

```
string s = Clipboard.GetText();
```

---

```
output(s) >> Trade Info\r\n\r\nNE62 -- NE62\r\n\r\nSymbol\t\tSide\t\tQuantity\t\tAvg Price\t\tClientAcct\t\t\r\n\r\nESU8\t\tBUY\t\t100\t\t2809.2500\t\t35199008\t\t\r\nFLT.V\t\tSELL\t\t15,000\t\t1.7040\t\tPRBCOAV\t\t\r\nTRST.TO\t\tSELL\t\t4,850\t\t7.1500\t\tPRBCOAV\t\t\r\nYGR.TO\t\tSELL\t\t5,200\t\t5.3806\t\tPRBCOAV\t\t\r\n"
```

I removed the top row (Trade Info NE62 -- NE62) using regex because it's variable for every user.

Then I used the following string to dynamically allocate columns. Every user has a variable length of column depending on what information they need

```
string columnarray = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf("\t\t\r\n\r\n"));
```

---

```
output(columnarray) >> Symbol\t\tSide\t\tQuantity\t\tAvg Price\t\tClientAcct\t\t\r\n\r
```

---

```
string[] ColArray = Regex.Split(columnarray, "\t\t");
foreach (string b in ColArray)
{
    d.Columns.Add(b);
}
```

The remaining string is stored inside another variable to be filled inside the datatable which is what I am having trouble figuring out. Below is the remaining value which i need to fill into the datatable.

**The preferred solution would be to loop through the string, split them every time you hit \t\t and put them in the same row, and escape to the next row once you hit \r\n.**

```
ESU8\t\tBUY\t\t100\t\t2809.2500\t\tB324aV\t\t\r\nFLT.V\t\tSELL\t\t15,000\t\t1.7040\t\tB324aV\t\t\r\nTRST.TO\t\tSELL\t\t4,850\t\t7.1500\t\tB324aV\t\t\r\nYGR.TO\t\tSELL\t\t5,200\t\t5.3806\t\tB324aV\t
```

---

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DGVUpload.Rows.Clear();
        DGVUpload.Columns.Clear();
        string sepo = "\t";
        string s = Clipboard.GetText();

        s = Regex.Replace(s, "[A-Za-z]{5}[ ][A-Za-z]{4}[\\r][\\n][\\r][\\n][A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[ ][-][-][ ][A-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[\\r][\\n][\\r][\\n]", "");

        string columnarray = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf("\t\t\r\n\r\n"));

        string dataArray = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\t\t\r\n\r\n"));
        dataArray = Regex.Replace(dataArray, "[\\t][\\t][\\r][\\n][\\r][\\n]", "");


        //string[] bitts = (s.Trim('\t')).Split(sepo.ToCharArray());
        //string[] bitts2 = bitts.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
        string[] ColArray = Regex.Split(columnarray, "\t\t");
        string[] DatArray = Regex.Split(dataArray, "\t\t");

        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        foreach (string b in ColArray)
        {
            d.Columns.Add(b);
        }

        DGVUpload.DataSource = d;


    }
```

The ideal result should look like this..

```
Ticker | Action | Quantity | Price     | Acc Number
---------------------------------------------------
ESU8   | BUY    | 100      | 2809.2500 | 900000 
FLT.V  | SELL   | 15,000   | 1.7040    | B324aV 
TRT.TO | SELL   | 4,850    | 7.1500    | f23AAA 
YGR.TO | SELL   | 5,200    | 5.3806    | 42ABBB
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following.  Is the issue that you're not splitting on the \r\n, so you're getting all the data in one big row?

Comment: @EvanM Hi Evan I updated the question hope its a little more helpful now. Yes I am having trouble figuring out how to fill all the columns in the same row by splitting \t\t and escaping to the next column once i hit \r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i devised a solution that seems to be working great. I used a parser to parse through the string and add to a dataTable after formatting the string so it's parsing friendly. Just posting it out here incase anyone else needs help in the future.

```
string[] ColArray = Regex.Split(columnarray, "\t\t");
string[] DatArray = Regex.Split(dataArray, "\t\t");
DatArray = DatArray.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

//Join all the split string using (+)
string datstring = string.Join("+", DatArray);

//Remove the additional (+) symbol infront of the \r\n\ to match array length        
datstring = Regex.Replace(datstring, @"[+\\r\\]\B", "");
DataTable d = new DataTable();

foreach (string b in ColArray{
    d.Columns.Add(b);                
    }
// use a parser to parse through the string and add the items to your datatable
using (var reader = new StringReader(datstring))
    {
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader)
        { HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false, Delimiters = new string[] { "+" } };
        while(!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            var drow = d.NewRow();
            drow.ItemArray = parser.ReadFields();
            d.Rows.Add(drow);
        }
     }
DGV.Datasource = d;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the question the codes below should do the job:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = CreateTable();
}

private DataTable CreateTable()
{
    var str = "ESU8\t\tBUY\t\t100\t\t2809.2500\t\tB324aV\t\t\r\nFLT.V\t\tSELL\t\t15,000\t\t1.7040\t\tB324aV\t\t\r\nTRST.TO\t\tSELL\t\t4,850\t\t7.1500\t\tB324aV\t\t\r\nYGR.TO\t\tSELL\t\t5,200\t\t5.3806\t\tB324aV\t";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("Ticker", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Action", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(double));
    dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));
    dt.Columns.Add("Acc Number", typeof(string));

    str = str.Replace("\t\t", " ");
    str = str.Replace(",", ".");
    str = str.Replace("\r\n", "");

    var r = str.Split();

    int rows = r.Length / 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    { 
        dt.Rows.Add(
            r[i * 5 + 0], 
            r[i * 5 + 1],                                  
            double.Parse(r[i * 5 + 2]),
            double.Parse(r[i * 5 + 3]),
            r[i * 5 + 4]);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi i updated the question a bit. This seems to work but it defeats the purpose of dynamically allocating columns based on the first row of data in the clipboard, because every user has a variable column numbers @L_J

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = @"Trade Info

NE62 -- NE62

Symbol      Side        Quantity        Avg Price       ClientAcct      

ESU8        BUY     100     2809.2500       35199008        
FLT.V       SELL        15,000      1.7040      tB324aV     
TRST.TO     SELL        4,850       7.1500      tB324aVV        
YGR.TO      SELL        5,200       5.3806      tB324aV";

var data = s.Split(new char[] { '\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.SkipWhile(x => !x.StartsWith("Symbol"))
.Skip(1)
.Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
.Select(d => new {
    Symbol = d[0],
    Side = d[1],
    Quantity = int.Parse(d[2].Replace(",","")),
    AvgPrice = decimal.Parse(d[3]),
    ClientAcct = d[4]
});

yourDataGridView.DataSource = data.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, this makes the table very hardcoded. Because every user has different columns and different rows depending on how they format their table on their end